# Django: which url does the LocaleMiddleware check?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-middleware

Our company provides both a API and a small number of widgets that are embedded in clients websites through Iframes.

Now we have a Belgian customer who wishes to use our widgets. As you know Belgium is bi-lingual, so we are making liberal use of both the `LocaleMiddleware` and the `{% trans 'string' %}` tags.

Now as I understand correctly the middleware checks the URL to see which language to use. When you first visit our clients website you get a large pop-up where you choose your language. After this popup your url changes to this format: `www.clientorg.be/fr_BE/rest-of-the-url`, so that should (hopefully) work just fine.

However, our widget is served through an Iframe. (`src = s2.oururl.com`) which contains no language value.

So my question is: Will Django be able to detect the language of the user? Or will it only be able to check 'our'  s2.url, meaning we need to contact our client and provide him with 2 urls to paste in the iframe, depending on the language the user chooses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's exactly what LocalMiddleware tries to do to determine the language:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/

> LocaleMiddleware tries to determine the user’s language preference by
>   following this algorithm:
>
> First, it looks for the language prefix in the requested URL. This is
>   only performed when you are using the i18n_patterns function in your
>   root URLconf. See Internationalization: in URL patterns for more
>   information about the language prefix and how to internationalize URL
>   patterns.
>
> Failing that, it looks for the LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY key in the current
>   user’s session.
>
> Failing that, it looks for a cookie.
>
> The name of the cookie used is set by the LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME
>   setting. (The default name is django_language.)
>
> Failing that, it looks at the Accept-Language HTTP header. This header
>   is sent by your browser and tells the server which language(s) you
>   prefer, in order by priority. Django tries each language in the header
>   until it finds one with available translations.
>
> Failing that, it uses the global LANGUAGE_CODE setting.